# How to declare dictionary with functions as values and keyed by integer?

Tags: swift, function, dictionary, swift2

```
struct Test {
    func isOk () -> Bool{
        return true
    }

    var mapping: [Int: () -> Bool] = [
        1: isOk
    ]

    func test() -> Bool {
        return mapping[1]()
    }
}
```

I got this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Test) -> () -> Bool' to expected dictionary value type '() -> Bool'
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing this weird type (`(Test) -> () -> Bool`) because [Swift instance methods are curried functions](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/).

If making `isOk` into a static method is acceptable, you can do this:

```
struct Test {
    static func isOk() -> Bool { //Make it static
        return true
    }

    var mapping: [Int : () -> Bool] = [
        1 : Test.isOk // Static method must be qualified by its parent type
    ]

    func test() -> Bool { //Bool return value necessary
        //TODO: remove force unwrapping.
        return mapping[1]!() //subscripting a Dict might return nil
    }
}
```

If `isOk` must remain as an instance method, you can do this:

```
struct Test {
    func isOk() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    var mapping: [Int : (Test) -> () -> Bool] = [ //change type
        1 : isOk
    ]

    //the instance method received from the dict needs an instance to act on
    func test(instance: Test) -> Bool { //Bool return value necessary
        //TODO: remove force unwrapping.
        return mapping[1]!(instance)() //curried function call
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[@AMomchilov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38130756/2976878) is dead right about why this is happening. At static scope (such as in `mapping`'s default value assignment), [instance methods are curried functions](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/) – meaning that they return a function that take a given instance to operate on as a parameter, rather than implicitly operating on `self` (as `self` doesn't refer to an instance at static scope).

Another potential solution to the ones already proposed if you don't wish to make `isOk` a static method and would like `mapping` to remain a `[Int : () -> Bool]`, is to make it `lazy`. This will allow you to access `isOk` in the assignment of `mapping`, as it's now at instance scope – therefore meaning the function type will be `() -> Bool`.

```
struct Test {
    func isOk () -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    lazy var mapping: [Int: () -> Bool] = [
        1 : self.isOk
    ]

    mutating func test() -> Bool {
        // you need to think about situations where mapping[1] returns nil
        // and deal with it in a more proper way than force unwrapping
        return mapping[1]!()
    }
}
```

The only caveat to this approach is that you'll need to mark `test()` as `mutating` – as the default value of a `lazy` variable will be set upon accessing it for the first time, thus mutating the struct.

Although a maybe even cleaner alternative (depending on the use case), is just to assign your function to the dictionary (or the dictionary itself) in the initialiser. This will allow you to keep `mapping` non-lazy, therefore meaning `test` doesn't have to be `mutating`.

```
struct Test {
    func isOk () -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    init() {
        mapping[1] = isOk
    }

    var mapping = [Int: () -> Bool]()

    func test() -> Bool {
        // you need to think about situations where mapping[1] returns nil
        // and deal with it in a more proper way than force unwrapping
        return mapping[1]!()
    }
}
```

Again, this ensures that you're at instance scope when assigning the method to the dictionary, thus ensuring that it has the signature `() -> Bool`.

Comment: I would use mapping[1]?() instead of mapping[1]!(), since it will be safer.